# Фактическое перемещение изображения после TransitionAnimation

Tags: android, анимация

Перемещаю свой `View` с помощью стандартной TranslateAnimation с `fillafter="true"`

```
 <translate
    android:duration="400"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
    android:toYDelta="100%" />
```

Однако его фактическое положение остается в начальной позиции (клики проходят на том месте, где была кнопка ДО перемещения).
Не понимаю, как сделать, чтобы `layoutParams` перезаписывались в соответствии с новой позицией или как это вообще сделать?
Читал что-то про Scene, но не уверен, что она подходит в данной ситуации.

Мне кажется вопрос актуальный, должен быть простой ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте `ObjectAnimator` для этих целей. Он меняет конкретно свойства `View`, а не двигает картинку, отрендеренную у `View`. [nineoldandroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/)

Comment: то, что надо! спасибо! )