# Работа с анимацией TranslateAnimation

Tags: java, android, android-animation

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста.

Проблема заклчается в том, объект view, двигается по экрану благодаря TranslateAnimation, я на него повесил OnClickListener, a он не работает. Получается, что для программы, он находится всегда на одном месте, и когда нажимаешь на то пустое место, он естественно срабатывает. Можна ли что то сделать?

Comment: Вам нужен `ObjectAnimator` (или метод `animate()` виджетов, что то же самое). Смотрите [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535706/177345) или [этот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/604733/177345) и множество других примеров по использованию этого класса (метода). Для поддержки  API < 11 используется библиотека *nineoldandroid*

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067778/button-is-not-clickable-after-translateanimation) это обсуждали.

В ответе, который отмечен верным говорится

> Да, это нормальное состояние, потому что анимации повторно меняют пиксели, но координаты остаются теми же

В ответе предлагается использовать `layout()` у `view` в конце анимации. Так делать нельзя, так как если, например, перевернуть устройство, то `view` будет там, где был с самого начала. В комментарие ниже об этом и говорится, в нем же предлагается использовать `LayoutParams`.

Вам надо чтобы слушатель работал **когда анимация закончится** или **когда анимация работает**? Если первое, то вам надо повесить на анимацию слушатель и в `onAnimationEnd` менять у `view` `LayoutParams`. Если второе, то скорее всего вам нужна циклическая смена `LayoutParams`, и причем в отдельном потоке.

Если у вас `view` перемещается в известное вам место (траектория прописана, она одна) то лучше в двух местах создать одинаковые `view`, и в конце анимации по очереди их делать невидимыми, Тоесть например кнопка сверху. Нужно, чтобы она была внизу. Вы нижнюю делаете невидимой, анимируете первую и когда она анимация закончится делаете невидимой первую, а вторую наоборот - видимой

Еще советую посмотреть в сторону `ViewPropertyAnimator`

Comment: А правильный в том обсуждении второй ответ, нужно использовать `ObjectAnimator` (или метод `animate()` у виджетов, что то же самое) вместо того, чтобы подпирать костыли :)

Comment: @pavlofff, понятно :)